# Ruby: How should I remove duplicate lines from an Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I may not be using the correct terminology but here goes..

I'm displaying IPS alerts on a dashboard app and there are many duplicate lines. For example, if one script kiddie is trying to brute force an RDP server, I could get 150 Alerts but could be slimmed down to about 5 because that's how many hosts they are going after. So I'm trying to remove the duplicate alerts, and I'm looking to use the sid, src_addr, and dst_addr as my metrics to determine if they are duplicates.

Currently I display `@filtered_snort_detail_query` using this code:

`This is my view`

```
<% if @filtered_snort_detail_query.count > 0 %>
  <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
        <th>Tag Info</th>
        <th>Message</th>
      </tr>
      <% @filtered_snort_detail_query.each do |d|
        text_msg = d['_source']['message']
        if d['_source']['message'].nil?
        end
      %>
          <tr>
            <td class='timestamp'><%= d['_source']['@timestamp'].to_time %></td>
            <td class='tags'><%= d['_source']['tags'] %></td>
            <td class='message'><%= text_msg %></td>
          </tr>
      <% end %>

    </table>
<% else %>
    <div> No Results Returned. </div>
<% end %>
```

`Here is my controller`

```
    if @es_snort_detail_query.count > 0
      @filtered_snort_detail_query = Array.new
      @es_snort_detail_query.each do |ips_detail|
        next if ips_detail['_source']['type'] != 'snort-ips'
        next if ips_detail['_source']['@timestamp'] < @ts
        @filtered_snort_detail_query.push(ips_detail)
      end
     end
```

Here is what I think I need to do to get the metrics I need to compare lines in my controller.
I'm just not sure the best way to look at each line of `@filtered_snort_detail_query` and build a new array to display in my view using these parameters:

show me all lines, but not if `sid_data`, `src_ip_data`, and `dst_ip_data` happen two or more times.

```
    if @es_snort_detail_query.count > 0
      @filtered_snort_detail_query = Array.new
      @es_snort_detail_query.each do |ips_detail|
        next if ips_detail['_source']['type'] != 'snort-ips'
        next if ips_detail['_source']['@timestamp'] < @ts
        @filtered_snort_detail_query.push(ips_detail)
      end
      if @filtered_snort_detail_query.count > 0
        ip_src = Array.new
        ip_dst = Array.new
        sid = Array.new
        @filtered_snort_detail_query.each do |find_ip, find_sid|
          unless find_ip.nil?
            sid_data = find_sid.scan(/\[\d+\:\d+\:\d+\]/)
            src_ip_data = find_ip.scan(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)
            dst_ip_data = find_ip.scan(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)
            sid.push(sid_data[0]) unless sid_data[0].nil?
            ip_src.push(src_ip_data[0]) unless src_ip_data[0].nil?
            ip_dst.push(dst_ip_data[1]) unless dst_ip_data[1].nil?
          end

        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if I misunderstood the question.

If you have a bunch of objects in an array, and you want to remove duplicates based on a subset of their properties, you can use the `uniq` method with a block:

```
queries.uniq do |query|
  [query.sid_data, query.src_ip_data, query.dst_ip_data]
end
```

It will compare the queries based on the array created in the block, and remove duplicates.

---

Go to http://www.compileonline.com/execute_ruby_online.php, copy and paste the code below, and click execute script in the top left.

```
queries = [
  { :a => "ab", :b => "ba" },
  { :a => "ab", :b => "xy" },
  { :a => "xy", :b => "xy" }
]

unique_queries = queries.uniq do |q|
  q[:a]
end

puts unique_queries
```

See? The comparaison was done only based on the value of the `:a` key. That's the same principle.

Comment: That is almost exactly what I need. I tried it and failed, because the timestamps are different the lines are not really unique. That's why I would like to use these fields to determine uniqueness `sid_data, src_ip_data, and dst_ip_data`

Comment: Well, that's exactly what this script should address. Let me update my answer. Also, which version of ruby are you using? 1.8.7 version of uniq might not take a block.

Comment: I'm using ruby 2.0.0p353.

Comment: Keep in mind that `uniq` doesnt modify the array in place, use `uniq!` for that.